# graphics not showing on resized subpanel?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am having issues with a small project im working on. I am trying to create a Moveable message panel when holding down the mouse button but i am stuck on one part.

I want to place the A small panel with a size of 50x30 pixels that contains the message "java" in it and have this small panel in a larger panel and place that panel into my JFrame.

However, when i do so the message "java" disappears and only the the small panel in the larger panel appears. I added borders to my panels to make sure that my panels were actually visible. Please help  and here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MovingPanel extends JFrame {
    private String message;
    private int x = 100;
    private int y = 100;

    public MovingPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        MessagePanel p1 = new MessagePanel("Java");
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED, 2));
        panel.setLayout(null);
        p1.setLocation(x, y);
        p1.setSize(50, 30);
        p1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));
        p1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(p1);
        add(panel);

     }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MovingPanel frame = new MovingPanel();

    frame.setSize(500, 500);

    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setTitle("Test Message Panel");

    frame.setVisible(true);

}

class MessagePanel extends JPanel {

    public MessagePanel(String s) {

        message = s;

    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawString(message, x + 20, y + 10);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @derstrom8 srry the website wouldnt let me add all the code for some reason. i just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use a simple JLabel component instead of your "MessagePanel".

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to understand is this.

- The second and third arguments of this `g.drawString(message, x + 20, y + 10);` method are the x and y location of the panel.
- With the above being said, you have to remember that it is the x and y location of the containing panel, which is `MessagePanel`.
- You have the size of your `MessagePanel` object set at 50, 30, yet you are trying to access a point 120 (x + 20) and 110 (100 + 10), which does not exist since you size the size of the panel.
- So now that's understood, let's say you want to paint the message at the very left corner of the MessagePanel, so you try and do this `g.drawString(message, 0, 0);`. This still would show anything as the point starts from the bottom left corner of the message, so the message would actually be riding just above the visible area.
- When drawing strings, you need to consider the [`FontMetrics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html), which allows you to get the size of the string you are trying to draw, so you can position the message exactly on the screen where you want it.
- A *simple* fix would be just set an x and y a little above 0, 0, like 15, 15. Though this might get your message to draw, it wouldn't be centered. You can keep on changing and getting different numbers to check if it is aligned in the middle, but the proper way is to use `FontMetrics`

---

As a said a *simple* (but maybe not desired) fix is to just change this

```
g.drawString(message, x + 20, y + 10);
```

To

```
g.drawString(message, 15, 15);
```

And you will see the message.

---

Instead of what you are doing though, this is how I would do it.

- Instead of using two panels, I would just use one - the one that's doing the painting.
- Don't set the size of it, instead override `getPrefferedSize` inside that class, to whatever size you want the main panel to me.
- When you draw, just draw a rectangle the size you want at the specified coordinates.
- Also draw the message in the same `paintComponent` method.
- call `pack()` on the JFrame.
- If you do the above, there's no need to try and move the location of the MessagePanel. Instead move the x and y coordinates when you call repaint, You can have offsets for the message. Like

  ```
  int boxX = 100;
  int boxY = 100;
  int messageOffset = 15;
  ```
- Then you can paint like this

  ```
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.drawRect(boxX, boxY, 50, 30);
      g.drawString(message, boxX + messageOffset, boxY + messageOffset);
  }
  ```
- Now in your action methods, just alter the `boxX` and/or `boxY` and call repaint.
- Also, if you want a thicker line, look into [Graphics2D API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/strokeandfill.html), you can `setStroke`.

Comment: thank you so much!!! But what I am trying to do is register the message panel that contains the message to a mouse listener interface so that I can drag the small message to different locations.

Comment: that's why I wanted two panels and a resized subpanel containing the message so that way it would be possible o move it. Unless there's another way?

Comment: You can still do it. Just do a little math. When you try and drag the mouse, check to make sure the points is within the bounds of the rectangle and repaint the rectangee inside the mousedragged

Comment: And btw, you want a `MouseMotionListener` for drag event, not a `MouseListener`